# A project can't reference another project of the same solution - the method or operation not implemented

Tags: c#, uwp, reference, projects-and-solutions

I would like to use some of methods from my c# console app project ("EPS logic") in UWP project ("EPS view") in same solution.

I tried that to add reference- [Calling methods from different Projects in one Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092708/calling-methods-from-different-projects-in-one-solution).

But when I tried to I got two errors:

```
Cannot add reference to project "EPS Logic"
```

and

```
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Additionaly I got some warnings like this about all classes from my EPS logic project:

```
warning DV2002: Class 'SequenceMaker' is not mapped to any Dependency Validation diagram
```

But I don't know if it's part of that problem. Should I not try to add anything to UWP project in first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to reference a console app from a UWP project; they are not compatible! If it is really just logic, you should create a .NET Standard class library or a UWP class library and put your logic there. You should be able to reference that just fine.

If you are wanting a console app *and* a UWP app with shared logic, split that logic out into a .NET Standard class library, then reference that from both the console and UWP projects.

Comment: I did exactly that - my solution has now: logic in .NET Standard class, view in UWP project, and additional console project for other tests - and it works! Thank you!